# Error in BCP Utility , import data from CSV file?

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

Using this BCP command for format file-

```
bcp DataBaseTablePath format nul -c -t, -r "0x0a" -f formatfilepath -S serveraddress -U username -P password
```

As I have specified   **-c**   option ,
that Performs the operation using a character data type.

**Problem-** loading data from csv file which has column data like-

> 02:38:22

This needs to be stored in **time data type** in my database.

But I am getting below error-

`Exception Msg : SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationSQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid character value for cast specificationBCP copy in failed`

But when I try to load data after deleting time column data from csv, its loading successfully.

Not able to Understand What causing issue?

Comment: What if you generate the format file without the `-c` flag? Also, it would be practical if we could see the format file in your question, along with a line of the data file for which the import fails.